# regular expression required to not to replace a text in single quotes

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have following regular expression:

```
(\b(?:ADD|EDIT|DELETE)\b[\s\S]*?)\bDATA\b([\s\S]*)
```

to replace `DATA` with `INTEGER, DECIMAL, STRING` depending on some criteria.

For example,
"ADD record with DATA 12" will replace "ADD record with INTEGER 12" after applying regular expression.

But if there is a statement like "ADD record with DATA 'My data'", and if I want to replace DATA with STRING using above regular expression, it will replace data in 'My data' also, like "ADD record with STRING 'My STRING'".

I am trying to create a regular expression that will not replace "data" word in single quotes. The regular expression should  only return data word which is outside of single quotes.

Comment: What regex tool/programming language are you using?

Comment: what do you intend by `[\s\S]*?` ?

Comment: @jhnc That's a workaround for regex flavors which do not support the DOTALL modifier `/s`. You could use any meta pair which has a negated counterpart like `[\d\D]*`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's good to know. I was actually wondering more about what should be allowed before DATA. I think an answer needs to know more about the allowable statement syntax otherwise it will be impossible to distinguish `...'...data...'...` from `...'...'...data...'...'...` (using `...` to mean something that doesn't contain single-quotes)

Comment: @jhnc OP hasn't provided enough context, particularly an example source and result string, for us to know the pitfalls and edge-cases of their problem.

Comment: I am using C++. Actually, the text will start from ADD or EDIT or DELETE  then some text in between (this text may contain DATA word in single quotes) then DATA then again some text. So I want to replace DATA word (which is not in single quotes) with a certain data type as I explained in my question. While replacing, DATA word in single quotes should get skipped

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to replace DATA with INTEGER, DECIMAL, STRING depending on the next text after 'DATA'.

```
txt.replace(/(?<=[a-z ]+)(\bDATA \d*\.?\d*)/gi, x => {
    if(/(?<=(data ))\d*\.\d+/gi.test(x)){
        return x.replace(/data/gi, 'DECIMAL');
    } else if(/(?<=(data ))\d+/gi.test(x)) {
        return x.replace(/DATA/gi, 'INTEGER');
    } else {
        return x.replace(/DATA/gi, 'STRING');
    }
})
```

Output:
[image]